How to disable checked rows from the interactive grid in oracle apex?
I want to disable checked rows in the interactive grid in Oracle Apex. How can achieve it?
Using JS or Handling it using any button?
I have selected 3 rows shown below Screenshot
enter image description here
I want to disable them as I checked them. how can I do that?
I tried all conventional methods from Oracle Apex but it did not worked at all.
I have an interactive Grid in which user wants if they check any number of rows say 10, they need a button. if they click on that button those 10 rows will freeze or become read-only. if the user wants to release it (make Editable) user should click on another button or that same button.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

No need to spam tags. There is only one tag relevant and that is the "oracle-apex" one. No one monitoring javascript or css will have a clue about your question

Can you explain the business requirement ? You're asking for a specific solution but what are you trying to achieve ? There might be better ways to tackle your issue.

@KoenLostrie I edited the question. Please let me know if you need more information on that

I would tackle this the following way

Create a button that processes the selected rows. By processing I mean set a flag on each record to indicate those rows are "frozen" or "disabled". To handle the selected rows you need to use javascript (getSelectedRecords ) to get the ids and then process them on the server, either with a callback process or with a dynamic action. One way to do it is described here.

Then use the feature "Allowed Row Operations Column" to render the selected rows then as not editable.




It did not working can you explain in more details please !

It is a lot of coding... - you're not asking a simple question but one that requires some work, I'm doing this just for fun and to learn something.I suggest you try this yourself and I'm happy to take a look. There is a workspace on apex.oracle.com, workspace name SO_HELP, user SO_78271783, password SO_78271783. It has sample data emp and dept installed. Feel free to implement what I suggested (I'm pretty sure it will work) and if it does not I'm happy to take a look.

Also, the answer "it did not work" is the worst comment to give on a forum since it provides no information whatsoever. If something doesn't work, explain what you have done in detail (by updating your answer, not in the comments) so others can help you figure out what went wrong.
